# three-master Pharaon vs. three-master Pharaons?

Tags: grammatical-number

This is the first sentence from the book "The Count of Monte Cristo".

> ...the arrival of the three-master Pharaon, from Smyrna, Trieste, and Naples.

I think this sentence means there are 3 kings in the group. How come  Pharaon is still singular here ?

Comment: It actually means *Pharaon* is a [ship with three masts](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/three–master).

Comment: I think it's clear from their translation efforts that the asker has researched meanings of 'master' and Pharaon'. My Chambers dictionary doesn't give 'ship with specified number of masts' as a definition of 'master' and the text has no indication by inverted commas or italics that Pharaon is a name rather than to be treated literally. I don't have voting rights but I'd make a plea for this to be kept on the grounds that it's a tricky passage and the OP attempt makes their research clear even if they've not detailed it.

Answer (score 4):

Having looked at your quote in context: "three-master, Pharaon, from Smyrna, Trieste, and Naples."
This is describing a ship, called 'Pharaon' which has three masts. 
I believe that the reference to 'Smyrna, Trieste, and Naples' means these are the names of the three ports the ship has visited before returning to its home port.